# Optimization of Saxon XQueryCompiler

Tags: java, saxon

I have found really strange behaviour of XQueryCompiler in saxon 9.9.1-4. When I run first XQuery, the compilation tooks a lot of time (400 ms) regardless on XQuery complexity - tested for example math:pi(). But when I "initialise" XQuery compiler via compiling something (eg. compiler.compile("1") ), then compiling of other queries are fast - the 400ms wait is no longer there.

It is really strange, why it happens ? If this behaviour is intended, why there is not such initialisation in the factory method Processor.newXQueryCompiler() ?

I have tested fast compilation flag and it does not seems to have any effect on this 400ms delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that you are measuring the cost of loading up the Java VM and the Saxon software, rather than the cost of compiling the actual query. It can take Java quite a time to "warm up" before all classes are loaded, commonly-used methods are JIT-compiled, and so on. You can easily observe this effect if you compile the same query 20 times, the time taken will slowly improve as Java does its optimizations.

Comment: Just note for others reading this - seems to be warming up of Java VM as the delay seems to occur only once and on the beginning of the process. So if you want quick XQuery queries from the beginning, you can use the trick with compiler.compile("1") in initialison phase ;-)